# Kanto pri la fakto ke nevido ≠ neekzisto

Tags: culture, music

Pro la lastaj demandoj pri antaŭjuĝoj pri Esperanto, mi ekmemoras esperantlingvan kanton kiu havas tekston similan al "ne povi vidi ion ne signifas ke ĝi ne ekzistas". Kaj poste estas ekzemploj de aferoj kiujn homoj emas ne kredi ĉar ili ne vidas ilin en la ĉiutaga vivo, inkluzive Esperanton. Tamen mi havas memortruon kaj ne plu povas memori nek la nomon, nek la grupon, nek la tekston. Ĉu iu povos helpi min trovi ĝin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eble temas pri *Preferindus* de *Strika Tango*

https://www.soundcloud.com/esperanta-muziko/strika-tango-preferindus

Comment: Jesja, ĝuste tion mi serĉis, dankon!